# How to use Coredata ordered relationships with NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

1. I have an Items Entity and a Tags Entity.
2. Items can have multiple Tags and Tags can be linked to multiple Items (many to many
   relationship).
3. The relationship is an "Ordered Relationship" (using Ordered relationship in IOS5) both ways.

I want to fetch all Items for a Tag using a NSFetchedResultsController.

Queries:

1. Is it even possible to use ordered relationships with NSFetchRequest and NSFetchedResultsController?
2. How do I specify the "Sort Descriptor"?
3. I tried two predicates. The first did not give any results, the second one did give results. Why does the first one does not work? Again how do I specify the sort descriptor to use the sorted order managed automatically by CoreData for this relationship?

Did not work: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags == %@", yyy];

Worked: But less efficient: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.tagID == %@", xxx];

Answer (score 2):

1 - Yes. It is possible. When you create your mapping file, make sure you change the relationship's type from an NSSet to an NSArray, like so:

```
    @class Tags

    @interface Entity : NSManagedObject
    ...
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSOrderedSet *tags;
    ...
    @end

    @interface Entity (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
    ...
    - (void)addEntityTags:(NSOrderedSet *)values;
    - (void)removeEntityTags:(NSOrderedSet *)values;
    ...
    @end
```

Change to:

```
    @class Tags

    @interface Entity : NSManagedObject
    ...
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *tags;
    ...
    @end

    @interface Entity (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
    ...
    - (void)addEntityTags:(NSArray *)values;
    - (void)removeEntityTags:(NSArray *)values;
    ...
    @end
```

2 - You can specify a sort descriptor when creating your fetch request, like so:

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest [NSFetchRequest new];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Entity" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];

    [fetchRequest.setEntity: entity];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"tags" ascending:<YES|NO>]];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags == %@", yyy]];

    NSFetchResultsController *myFetchResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext setcionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
    myFetchResultsController.delegate = self;

    [fetchRequest release]; // Forget that if using ARC.

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![myFetchResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to fetch data: %@", error);
    }
```

3 - If you use the property, you shouldn't need to specify a predicate for your tags. If you want to further sort your tags, you can simply use a sort descriptor on that array, like this:

```
    NSSortDescriptor *tagDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"<tags field to sort on>" ascending:<YES|NO>];
    NSArray *sortedTags = [tagsProperty sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:descriptors]];
```

You can simply read from that property for your tags.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that. Why is it required to change NSSet to NSArray? Btw its NSOrderedSet for ordered relationship. Is that what you meant? An Item can have many tags and thats why I do not want to use keypath to fetch all objects in one go.

Comment: I always use an NSArray anyway so I can apply a sort descriptor to it if necessary. It doesn't take anything away. I think the NSOrderedSet will keep the order in which the tags were inserted in CoreData (not sure about that though). CoreData always fetches faulted relationships. It will resolve the relationship as soon as you try to access the data. Don't worry about loading ALL the objects at once.

Comment: Another question: Why did the following predicate did not work: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags == %@", yyy];

This one worked: but I think it is less efficient: [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY tags.tagID == %@", xxx];

Comment: The reason is that the first predicate will expect a ManagedObject instance to match, meaning you would need to fetch the actual tags from CoreData and pass a result from that fetch to that predicate. The second one will work with a literal value.

Comment: Wait a minute. That predicate thing you're doing in #3, does that mean that you're trying to fetch all items with a specific tag? Because your original question is about fetching all tags for an item.

Comment: My bad. I typed it wrong. I am indeed trying to fetch all Items for a Tag (hence ANY tags == %@). This fetch was working in another project for me for unordered list, but this does not return any results for ordered relationship

Comment: Okay, that'll change my answer dramatically. Here's an interesting fact: from Apple's documentation, NSOrderedSet doesn't seem to be extending NSSet, which has a method called "filterSetUsingPredicate". There are no such thing with NSOrderedSet. Maybe an ordered set is not what you need here.

Comment: Go ahead and try to change that property in your mapping file to use an NSArray instead of NSOrderedSet. See if your predicate works with that. NSArray will preseve the current order.

Comment: Did not work. The first query still does not work. The second works.

Comment: I posed a new related question. I ended up writing my own ordered relationship implementation. One small issue with that. If you would be kind enough to have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12381585/nssortdescriptor-with-to-many-relationship